# Cant find Lombok constructor for derived class

Tags: java, generics, lombok

I am running into problems using Lombok when I set an enum in the base class.

I have the following code:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class AdminCommand<T extends AdminCommandType, P>  {
  T type;
  P payload;

}
```

T is an enum type, P is the payload I want to generate.  I want to generate classes based on AdminCommand, there the child classes have their own set types.

I am also using this interface to generate my enum:

```
public interface AdminCommandType {}
```

I am trying to extend the Admin class using the following:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestCommand<T extends AdminCommandType, O> extends AdminCommand {
  enum TestCommandType implements AdminCommandType {
    FOO
  }
}
```

My problem comes when I try to instantiate a version of TestCommand.

```
TestCommand<TestCommand.TestCommandType, "Any POJO Class"> testCommand
    = new TestCommand(TestCommand.TestCommandType.FOO, payload);
```

I get an error saying that no constructor can be found.

This worked when I made the T based on an enum in the base class, but this fails when I make the T based on an interface.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lombok @AllArgsConstructor doesn't call super() so you need to create constructor manually for derived classes

Comment: Thanks.  And I ran into another problem, GSON doesn't play nicely with inheirited classes.